# Openshift 4.5.18 - Application is not available

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-applications, openshift

I want to deploy my web application in Openshift cluster running on AWS cloud. I'm using `expose` command to make it available externally:

`oc expose service svcname`

But when I try to access it, I get this error:
[image]

The web application is running not on 8443; it's running on port 2553 using https.
We don't want to run it on 8443.
I am able to connect to webapp using `oc port-forward` but I want to make it work
by exposing through route command.
Is there something wrong in my approach?

## Update

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-svc
  labels:
    app: mywapp
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 2553
    nodePort: 30000
  selector:
    app: mywapp
```

The same service I am using on minishift and able to use, using the IP address of minishift locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was solved by using `re-encrypt`. I used the Openshift certificate to achieve this. By using the Openshift one doesn't have to worry about the certificate getting expired and all.

The following link has helped me big time:

https://www.openshift.com/blog/self-serviced-end-to-end-encryption-approaches-for-applications-deployed-in-openshift
https://www.openshift.com/blog/self-serviced-end-to-end-encryption-for-kubernetes-applications-part-2-a-practical-example
https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/11/22/dynamically-creating-java-keystores-openshift/

Comment: The references are excellent and I can't find it easily through googling.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to make sure that both your `Service` and your `Route` have the correct port specified.

- Check your `Service` for the `port` and the `targetPort`. You can find more information in the Kubernetes documentation: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#defining-a-service
- Check that your `Route` has specified the correct `port` in the `spec`. You can also use `oc expose service svcname --port=2553` to create the Route based on the Service.
- In your description you also noted that you are terminating TLS, so potentially you'll need to create a "passthrough" or "reencrypt" Route, which is easiest done using the following commands:

  - `oc create route passthrough myroute-passthrough --service=svcname --port=2553`
  - `oc create route reencrypt myroute-reencrypt --service=svcname --prt=2553`

You can find more information on secured Routes here: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/networking/routes/secured-routes.html

Comment: Hi, as far as I know I am not terminating TLS, how did you arrive at that I am terminating it. Can you please throw some light. I am just using the port 2553 instead of standard HTTPS port. Am I doing something wrong? I am new to TLS, Kubernetes and Openshift.

Comment: Quote: "[..] it's running on port 2553 using https [..]". If you do not need anything TLS/HTTPS-related, then you can just use `oc expose service svcname --port=2553`.

Comment: I need https. If you know about any page/blog where this setup is shown fully please provide me.

Comment: How to create the key and crt file and where to keep them? How the ingress controller will know about it?